# Programmatic authentication in Java EE 6

Tags: java, security, jakarta-ee, java-ee-6, rbac

is it possible to authenticate *programmatically* a user in Java EE 6?

Let me explain with some more details:

I've got an existing Java SE project with Servlets and hibernate; where I manage manually all the authentication and access control:

```
class Authenticator {
    int Id
    string username
}

Authenticator login(string username, string password) ;

void doListData(Authenticator auth) {
    if (isLoggedIn(auth)) listData();
    else doListError
}

void doUpdateData (Authenticator auth) {
    if (isLoggedAsAdmin(auth)) updateData() ;
    else doListError();
}

void doListError () {
    listError() ;
}
```

And Im integrating J2ee/jpa/servlet 3/... (Glassfish 3) in this project.

I've seen anotations like :

```
@RolesAllowed ("viewer")
void doListdata (...) {
    istData() ;
}

@RolesAllowed("admin")
void doUpdateData (...) {
    updateData() ;
}

@PermotAll
void dolisterror () {
    listerror() ;
}
```

but *how* can I manually state, in login(), that my user is in the admin and/or viewer role?

Comment: Thank you for your ansers,

login(java.lang.String user, java.lang.String password) 

is what I want to do: instead of login in my users, I need to login a specific role:

login("admin", "admin") ;

Comment: From my experience, programmatic login can require different code based on what application server you're using. Something to keep in mind.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hi this is covered pretty well in the [sun java ee 6 tutorial](http://java.sun.com/javaee/6/docs/tutorial/doc/gjiie.html).

Answer (score 1):

First make sure you are using Servlet 3.0/3.1. Servlet 2.4 does not have the login method

```
    @WebServlet(name="LoginServlet", urlPatterns={"/LoginServlet"})
    public class TutorialServlet extends HttpServlet {
      protected void processRequest(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
        response.setContentType("text/html;charset=UTF-8");
        String user = request.getParameter("user");
        String password = request.getParameter("password");
        //TODO check is user and password not null

        try (PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();){
           request.login(user, password);
           //perhaps redirect to another page on success
        } catch (ServletException e) {
            //perhaps redirect to another page to login failure
            throw new ServletException(e);
        } 
      }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for your ansers, I took a while to understand it, but you're both right,

```
login(java.lang.String user, java.lang.String password)
```

is what I want to do. Instead of login in *my* users, I need to login a specific role:

```
login("admin", "admin") ;
...
```

:)

Comment: Edit your original question if you want to provide feedback or a more detailed question. Or add comments to specific answers.

Comment: Thanks, I was a bit confused with two accounts (I thought first post was anonymous and therefore not editable)